# Format time to show hours and minutes only

Tags: commcare

I would like to format the time so that it is easily readable in a case list.

I am collecting the time of a follow-up appointment in 1 hour increments.

What is the right syntax to achieve this?

Is it better to format the time in a case list calculation or within the form?

Context:

Appointment time, is a time question.

The default for time is saved as 13:00:00.000-05

I want to use format-date to make the time information to appear as 13:00.

`format-date(/data/appointment_time, '%H:%M')` is not accepted.

Answer (score 1):

`format-date` doesn't work for times, just for dates and datetimes. CommCare generally treats times like basic strings, so you can use substr: `substr(appointment_time, 0, 5)`

Answer (score 0):

What sort of error message are you getting for `format-date(/data/appointment_time, '%H:%M')`? You might need to cast the question to a date or time first:

`format-date(date(/data/appointment_time), '%H:%M')`

(I don't know if commcare has a date/time data type besides dates, but you could try something like `time()` if `date()` doesn't work, although I don't see such a function listed in the [documentation](https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/CommCare+Functions)).